# Django Ajax: Call a specific python script within a directory of multiple python script

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-urls

Here's the code in the urls.py:

```
from djangotest.ajax.ajax_test import ajaxTest
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', handlerView),
path('ajax/', ajaxTest)]
```

Here's the code in the python script named ajax_test under the ajax folder:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
def ajaxTest(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

And here's the javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/',
    type: 'get', 
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('Encountered an error');
    }
});
```

When I run the server, the site alerts "Hello World" which means the code is correct. Now, my question here is this: Let's say I'll add another python script in the ajax folder named greetings(.py) with the function Greet that returns "Good day!". How do I specify which python script should the ajax call (for example, the greetings.py)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate URL for each function in the ajax_test file and called that function when hit on that URL.

```
from djangotest.ajax.ajax_test import ajaxTest, greetingTest
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
      path('', handlerView),
      path('ajax/hello_word', ajaxTest)
      path('ajax/greet', greetingTest)
    ]
```

Function in ajax_test:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
def greetingTest(request):
    return HttpResponse("Good day!")
```

Do call from JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/hello_world',
    type: 'get', 
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('Encountered an error');
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/greet',
    type: 'get', 
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('Encountered an error');
    }
});
```